# Bigquery ORDER BY (count )

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery

I want to run following query into Bigquery

```
SELECT table1.field1, COUNT(table1.fiels2)
FROM table1
GROUP BY table1.fiels1
ORDER BY COUNT(table1.fiels2)
DESC limit 10;
```

I am getting error Error: (L1:282): expression 
    COUNT([metamx_magnetic_share.adops001.cookie], DESC) in ORDER BY is invalid

But same query I am successfully ran on Vertica.

Any kind of help/suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can sort by an alias, but not a function, so try:

```
SELECT table1.field1, COUNT(table1.fiels2) as cnt
FROM table1
GROUP BY table1.fiels1
ORDER BY cnt
DESC limit 10;
```

The documentation is [here](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#orderby).